# where to delete database and close connection after all tests using mocha

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm trying to figure out where to put a function to delete database and close connection after all tests have run.

Here are my nested tests:

```
//db.connection.db.dropDatabase();
//db.connection.close();

describe('User', function(){
    beforeEach(function(done){
    });

    after(function(done){
    });

    describe('#save()', function(){
        beforeEach(function(done){
        });

        it('should have username property', function(done){
            user.save(function(err, user){
                done();
            });
        });

        // now try a negative test
        it('should not save if username is not present', function(done){
            user.save(function(err, user){
                done();
            });
        });
    });

    describe('#find()', function(){
        beforeEach(function(done){
            user.save(function(err, user){
                done();
            });
        });

        it('should find user by email', function(done){
            User.findOne({email: fakeUser.email}, function(err, user){
                done();
            });
        });

        it('should find user by username', function(done){
            User.findOne({username: fakeUser.username}, function(err, user){
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Nothing seems to work. I get      Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can define a "root" `after()` hook before the 1st `describe()` to handle cleanup:

```
after(function (done) {
    db.connection.db.dropDatabase(function () {
        db.connection.close(function () {
            done();
        });
    });
});

describe('User', ...);
```

Though, the error you're getting may be from the 3 asynchronous hooks that aren't informing Mocha to continue. These need to either call `done()` or skip the argument so they can be treated as synchronous:

```
describe('User', function(){
    beforeEach(function(done){ // arg = asynchronous
        done();
    });

    after(function(done){
        done()
    });

    describe('#save()', function(){
        beforeEach(function(){ // no arg = synchronous
        });

        // ...
    });
});
```

[From the docs](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/#asynchronous-code):

> By adding a callback (usually named `done`) to `it()` Mocha will know that it should wait for completion.

Comment: Actually, I get this error the 2nd time running make test: `  ✖ 1 of 5 tests failed:

  1) User #save() "before each" hook:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded`

Comment: @chovy It's giving you the direction -- '*"before each" hook*". So, you have a `beforeEach` that isn't finishing, probably because you've named the argument to accept a callback but then aren't calling it. With Mocha, you have to either leave it unnamed (0 arguments) -- `function () { ... }` -- or name it and call it -- `function (done) { done(); }`.

Comment: I am now getting a different error: https://gist.github.com/a8217751061ad6e738b9 1)  "after all" hook:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded

Comment: @chovy The source of the error doesn't appear to be in that file. Though, I ran a slightly modified version: https://gist.github.com/77caf41f4ee62a7fedc0

Comment: i had to increate my --timeout to 4000 because deleting database apparently lags a second or two.

Comment: [I'm also having this problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664061/using-should-js-with-mocha-asynchronously-giving-more-errors-than-expected)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it a bit different.

1. I removed all documents in the "before" hook - found it a lot faster than dropDatabase().
2. I used Promise.all() to make sure all documents were removed before exiting the hook.

   ```
   beforeEach(function (done) {

       function clearDB() {
           var promises = [
               Model1.remove().exec(),
               Model2.remove().exec(),
               Model3.remove().exec()
           ];

           Promise.all(promises)
               .then(function () {
                   done();
               })
       }

       if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 0) {
           mongoose.connect(config.dbUrl, function (err) {
               if (err) {
                   throw err;
               }
               return clearDB();
           });
       } else {
           return clearDB();
       }
   });
   ```